# Default Grails '/' controller mapping not resolving properly

Tags: grails, groovy, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

This one has been driving me crazy today.  Since upgrading to Grails 1.2 and Weblogic 10.3  the default root mapping for "/" stopped working. Here's what I have...

I have this URL mapping:

```
"/"(controller:"IGive", action:"index" )
```

I have a controller named IGiveController with an index closure

```
def index = {
    render "foo"
}
```

When I go to my application running in the embedded Tomcat and Jetty with http://localhost:8080/mycontext/ I get "foo" returned property. But when I build a war and deploy to Weblogic 10.3 I get a 404.

I downgraded to Grails 1.1.2 and it still didn't work on Weblogic 10.3 but the error was more descriptive

```
Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/index.gsp]
```

So it seems like it's completely ignoring my URL Mapping for "/" but other URL Mappings that are deeper are working.  Any clues??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is more related to Weblogic - I am seeing the same on Weblogic 9.2 - but not on Tomcat or Jetty. Doesn't hit my UrlMapping:

```
"/"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
```

I think Weblogic is being smart and converting / -> index.gsp which then comes back as a 404.

There is a slightly ugly workaround - just add a mapping like this:

```
"/index.gsp"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
```

and that seems to do the trick. Anyone have a better way to fix this???

Comment: thanks mate, wow you just made my day! I registered a bug in Jira later today

Comment: This workaround also worked in a wildfly8 .war deployment which otherwise would show index.gsp not found when accessing the root: `"/index.gsp"(view:"/index")`

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to a Grails 1.2 bug. See [GRAILS-5609](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5609) and this [thread](http://old.nabble.com/before-Interceptor-not-triggered-for-filter-with-global-scope-(Grails-1.2.0)-td26912181.html) in Grails forum. It is fixed in 1.2.1. It seems that 1.2 introduced some regression bugs with UrlMappings...